# GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no by default

Tags: git

In my git (v 1.7.10.2), I have to do the following in my terminal:

```
 GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no
 export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT
```

So, everytime I merge, I am not force to put a message.

Where should I put this, so by default it gets this set up and I don't have to type it everytime I open the terminal in my MAC?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can put it in:

```
.bash_profile
```

Open a terminal

```
nano $HOME/.bash_profile
```

and add the line

```
export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no
```

Don't forget to open a new terminal for this to work.

Comment: echo 'export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no' >> $HOME/.bash_profile && . $HOME/.bash_profile

Comment: Depending on your set up this may need to go it `.bashrc` instead. It depends on whether or not you're running bash with `--login` or not. Macs and Ubuntu at least have different defaults for this.