# Git makes a merge commit but as a normal (non-merge) commit

Tags: git, merge

Make a merge commit with no conflicts, `Ctrl-C` in Git Bash, and then commit. Git makes a normal (non-merge) commit but with the merge commit message. It looks like a bug to me.

***Update***: I have `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=yes` (other than `no`) in `.bashrc` with an external editor configured.

This is very confusing later on as the repo topology would show that the branch is not merged in and there is not an easy way to find out when the merge was made.

Git should still stay in a `MERGING` state. This does not happen in case of conflicts (at least I'm not able to repro), as I get a `(master|MERGING)` prompt till I resolve the conflicts and commit, which correctly goes as a merge commit.

**Update**:

This is a bug that affects all distributions which have an external editor (`core.editor`) configured. The fix is currently on the `pu` branch of Git repo by Michael J Gruber.

See commit [`9d89b3552`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d89b3552) ("merge: save merge state earlier", 2017-08-23)

> merge: save merge state earlier If the `git merge` process is killed
>   while waiting for the editor to finish, the merge state is lost but
>   the prepared merge msg and tree is kept. So, a subsequent `git commit`
>   creates a squashed merge even when the user asked for proper merge
>   commit originally.

**Update:**

This is fixed in Git 2.14.2 in commit [6e6ba65a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e6ba65a7) ("Merge branch 'mg/killed-merge'", 2017-08-26).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748344/git-merge-autoedit-no-by-default Try puting it in the `.bash_profile`

Comment: Seems like a Windows-ish bug: I cannot reproduce it on my system. But Git should either clean up *both* the merge state ("future commit is a merge") left behind (it seems to be doing this part) *and* the provided commit message, or clean up *neither*; doing one without the other just seems wrong.